# Transparent Section in TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `TableView` I use static cells. I take one section and in this section there are five cells(static cells). Now I want to make the whole section or these five cells transparent. That means I can see the  `Table View Controller` background through the cells. How can I do that?

I have gone through many solutions. But not solved.

Edit:

May be many of you are not clear about my question. I want the cell like the below image. it is downloaded image and there will be section which is not available in this image. I am just using this image to clear the question. Look at the image the cell background is transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this in the most simple way possible:
[image]

In storyboard select the static cells you want to appear transparent and select the background colour of 'Group table view background colour' or R235,G235,B241.

[image]

Then move the separator (the line in between) by moving it off screen by setting the below settings. [image]

If you still want the line ignore the above or if you want to change its colour use

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
tableView.separatorColor = //ADD COLOR HERE
}
```

Then you can add content to these cells as you would normally as I have added the label and UIImage View above.

**!!However, the less simple but best way to achieve this is by creating custom cells and using dynamic prototypes. You can find many tutorials on how to do this online.**

Answer (score 0):

you have to clear color to contentview of cell,also to the tableview cell and now i think you will be able to see the background and check now

Comment: have u taken the prototype cell?

Comment: if you have taken prototypecell then just go to property inspector and select clear color for background color in both content view of the cell as well the tableview cell no need to write code why to waste the code and time after that . and if you have not done so write  
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0):

just add below code for tableview

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override your `TableViewCell`'s `awakeFromNib` to set it's own background color and it's contentView's background color to `clearColor`:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = .clear            
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tableView with clear background color. Also tableView cell and contentView backGround color as Clear color.

For this add this Line in viewDidLoad Methods.

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Add this line in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method.

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```